# Can I create this type of event in C#?

Tags: c#, events

I have a List in my custom user control. I'd like the control to redraw the each Image in the List whenever the contents of that list is changed. Either a movement, addition or removal of an items should fire an event.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WebServiceScanner
{
    public partial class imageList : UserControl
    {
        public imageList()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public List<Image> Images { get; set; }

        public void AddImage(Image image)
        {
            Images.Add(image);
        }

        public void RemoveImage(Image image)
        {
            Images.Remove(image);
        }

        public void MoveImageLeft(int index)
        {
            Image tmpImage = Images[index];
            Images[index] = Images[index - 1];
            Images[index - 1] = tmpImage;
        }

        public void MoveImageLeft(int index)
        {
            Image tmpImage = Images[index];
            Images[index] = Images[index + 1];
            Images[index + 1] = tmpImage;
        }
    }
}
```

Can this be done?

Thanks for your guidance! Eager to learn!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) instead of a [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) and handle its [CollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375.aspx) event.

Comment: Sounds exactly what I'm looking for! I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class imageList : UserControl
    {

        public event OnChange;

        public imageList()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public List<Image> Images { get; set; }

        public void AddImage(Image image)
        {
            Images.Add(image);
            this.OnChange();
        }

        public void RemoveImage(Image image)
        {
            Images.Remove(image);
            this.OnChange();
        }

        public void MoveImageLeft(int index)
        {
            Image tmpImage = Images[index];
            Images[index] = Images[index - 1];
            Images[index - 1] = tmpImage;
            this.OnChange();
        }

        public void MoveImageLeft(int index)
        {
            Image tmpImage = Images[index];
            Images[index] = Images[index + 1];
            Images[index + 1] = tmpImage;
            this.OnChange();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It may be advisable to also make the `Images` property read-only or private, unless it really _needs_ to be publicly settable.  Otherwise it's possible to alter the list without calling the desired methods.

Comment: Can you explain what the this.OnChange() method does?

Comment: it raises the onchange event which you can handle outside of the class

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using the BindingList. The differences are discussed in here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284663/...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284663/difference-between-observablecollection-and-bindinglist)