# Trying to understand different behavior in binding for DataGrid between WindowsForms and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

In Windows Forms I used:

```
dataGridView.DataSource = new BindingList<MyItem>();
```

The equivalent in WPF seems to be:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = new BindingList<MyItem>();
```

What I don't understand (and perhaps I'm doing something wrong) is that in the WPF case, the binding doesn't seem to be bidirectional. That is to say: when I modify a `MyItem`, it is not automatically reflected in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `ObservableCollection<MyItem>`.
2. `MyItem` must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise `PropertyChanged` when any of its property values changes.

That'll update the grid cells.

3. If you plan to do anything much with WPF, learn MVVM and use `Binding`. Assigning a collection to a property doesn't bind it.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid
    x:Name="dataGrid"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemCollection}"
    ... 
    />
```

You can also create a Binding programmatically, if you really want to make a lot of extra work for yourself.

[Seems like ObservableCollection has some improvements over BindingList](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9533823/424129).