# Why can't I use array value in a ObservableCollection for binding?

Tags: c#, arrays, binding

I want to dispalay some byte values and their binary values.like this:[My UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wg2e3.png).

**my coding:
this is the item source:**

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ObservableCollection<MyRegs> regs = new ObservableCollection<MyRegs>()
        {
            new MyRegs(0x12),
            new MyRegs(0x23),
            new MyRegs(0x34)
        };
        RegsList.ItemsSource = regs;
    }
```

**this is custom data:**

```
public class MyRegs
{
    public MyRegs(byte val)
    {
        this.RegValue = val;

        this.Bits = new bool[] { true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false };
    }

    private byte regValue;
    public byte RegValue
    {
        get { return regValue; }
        set
        {
            regValue = value;
        }
    }

    private bool[] bits;
    public bool[] Bits
    {
        get
        {
            return bits;
        }
        set
        {
            bits = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Xaml: by the way, Can I use a template to get those checkboxes**

```
<Grid>
<ListView x:Name="RegsList">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox  Text="{Binding Path=RegValue,Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource sResource1}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Bits[7],Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Bits[6],Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Bits[5],Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Bits[4],Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Bits[3],Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Bits[2],Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Bits[1],Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Bits[0],Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**but when I check the CheckBox,it doesn't set Bits value.Why???**

I haved used the ObservableCollection,it didn't work too.

If i use bool type not bool[] type,it workes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `MyRegs` class does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged, so your UI elements have no way of knowing when your values get changed. You must implement that interface on your class and call `NotifyPropetyChanged` in the appropriate setters.

Second, ObservableCollection only sends update notifications when items are *added* or *removed* from the collection, not when items' properties have been updated.

Comment: A BindingList<T> would do both, inser/delete and modify notifications

Comment: BindingList<T> was designed for WinForms and is not properly supported for WPF. See:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532629/why-not-bindinglist-in-wpf

Comment: First of all, I think NotifyPropertyChanged doesn't matter with the Set Accessor.In the fact,RegValue can be seted when I edit the TextBox.

Comment: Second, ObservableCollection only sends update notifications when items are added or removed from the collection, not when items' properties have been updated.----- I agree.

Comment: Back to my question，it doesn't go to the Setter when I check those CheckBoxs.How to explain this,maybe the binding doesn't work.How can I fix it.