# How to assign PropertyChanged event handler to ObservableCollection owner

Tags: c#, observablecollection, propertychanged

I need to handle the PropertyChanged event of an item in an ObservableCollection within the owner of the ObservableCollection. There has to be a more elegant way than:

```
ObservableCollection(MyViewModel) myViewModels = new ObservableCollection<MyViewModel>();
LoadMyViewModels(myViewModels); // populates the collection
foreach (MyViewModel myViewModel in myViewModels)
{
    myViewModel.PropertyChanged += PropertyChangedEventHandler(MyViewModelPropertyChanged);
}
```

I'd like to pass the MyViewModelPropertyChanged event handler into LoadMyViewModels so I don't have to traverse the collection twice (once on load and once on event assignment).

MyViewModelPropertyChanged sets properties on the containing view that are reflected on the UI (the collection is bound to a TreeView and I need to enable/disable fields in the UI based on whether the item has been checked).

I've looked at most if not all the cited postings, but I'm a bit lost.

The above code does what I need it to do, but I know there's a better way. Please cite the appropriate reference or code sample.

Thanks.

Comment: +1 I have always done this too, would be interested in any responses you get here.

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to traverse the collection twice? Is it just a redundancy issue?

Comment: Not really a redundancy issue, I'm just looking to see if there's a more elegant way. Above works fine.

Answer (score 0):

A [`BindingList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) may give you what you need...

> [`BindingList` relays item change notifications when its items implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284663/difference-between-observablecollection-and-bindinglist)