# Get notified of collection changes

Tags: c#, collections, delegates, notifications

My class has a public List field. I want to detect when someone changes this collection. However, writing my own Add/Remove wrapper around this collection seems wasteful. Is there a way to get notifications about changes in collection with delegates or something like that?

Answer (score 3):

Use `ObservableCollection<T>` instead
you may find reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx).

Comment: It seems that it's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There already exists a collection you've described and it's called [`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx).

It has [`CollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375.aspx) event, so just subscribe your event handler there and i'll get called every time item is added or removed from collection..

Answer (score 0):

Use `BindingList<T>` instead. It offers a `ListChanged` event. It is also accepted as `DataSource` in many controls such as a Listbox or a Grid.

As mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4284805/245495) the `BindingList` offers a lot more than `ObservableCollection`

If you want to change a list in a listbox and changes to that list be reflected to the UI, you can set a `BindingList<>` as datasource to the Listbox and then simply manipulate the list. The Listbox will handle the `ListChanged` event and will display changes without having to manually do it by your self.

If you are going to use it in Winforms you should go with BindingList and if you are going to use it on a WPF app then go with ObservableCollection.