# Combobox binded to a list. Adding new item to the list does not affect combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox, datasource

There is following code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<string> names = new List<string> { "aa", "bb", "cc" };

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        comboBox1.DataSource = names;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        names.Add("dd");
    }
}
```

When i click on the button i want to add new value to source list and expect that combobox would be instantly updated to include that value. But it's not. Why?
In general, what's is the easiest proper way to connect List to a combobox the way that adding/removing items in list affects combobox directly?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a `BindingList` which raises a `ListChanged` event when the content of the list is changed.

```
BindingList<string> names = new BindingList<string> { "aa", "bb", "cc" };
```

For the difference between `ObservableCollection` and `BindingList` see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4284805/1401257) answer, which is much better than what I can provide.

---

If you have to keep the data in a normal `List` you can wrap the list in a `BindingSource` like this:

```
private BindingSource source; //property
...
   source = new BindingSource(names, "");
   comboBox1.DataSource = source;
```

And then add to the source:

```
source.Add("3");
```

The `BindingSource` will add items to the underlying list and raise the `ListChanged` event.

If you cannot use that solution either, I cannot think of anything else than just resetting the `DataSource` when you update the list:

```
names.Add("dd");
comboBox1.DataSource = null;
comboBox1.DataSource = names;
```

Comment: @Javidan Yes. But it doesn't raise an event if it is the custom types members you are changing. (eg. if you are displaying a property called `name` from an object and you change the value of `name`).

Comment: I read the link you given in your solution, really if not your answer i will not be aware about it. Thanks

Comment: This works. But i need to leave List<string> since that is just an example and in real project i can't change List to BindingList. Is there any way?

Comment: You can use `BindingList<string>` and create property like `MyList` and there put only `get` part returns like `BindingList<string>.ToList()`.

Comment: @clumpter I have added a possible solution that does not require any changes to the list.  But I will recommend looking into another approach.

Comment: @MAV solution with resetting datasource works good but it doesn't look right if you know what i mean.

Comment: @clumpter I know what you mean. Found a third solution if you can use that one.

Comment: @MAV for now i ended up with resetting datasource.

Answer (score 1):

It occurs because when your `List` is changed there is no event occurred to inform `ComboBox` about changes. Use `ObservableCollection<string>` instead of `List<string>` . It is like `List`, but have features.  `ObservableCollection<string>` follows `INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged` interfaces, and these are needed events.

Comment: ObservableCollection<string> doesn't automatically update combobox either.

Comment: I think it must be solve your problem. But anyway, use `BindingList<string>` as in solution of @MAV