# Binding (and refreshing) a List<T> to a ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, collections

I have two ListBoxes and I want to move items between them. The code looks like this:

```
    private void FillItems()
    {
        allItems = GetAllItems();
        availableItems = new List<string>(allItems);
        selectedItems = new List<string>();

        itemsListBox.DataSource = availableItems;
        selectedItemsListBox.DataSource = selectedItems;
    }

    private void addItemButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var itemsToAdd = itemsListBox.SelectedItems;
        foreach (string item in itemsToAdd)
        {
            availableItems.Remove(item);
            selectedItems.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Simple enough. I move strings from one list into another.

Now this doesn't work, just as it shouldn't. I realise that it's missing some way of notifying about collection change. So I tried these options:

1. Calling `Refresh()` on the list boxes. No avail.
2. Using an extra layer of data binding (`BindingSource`). Also no avail.
3. Calling `ResetBindings()` on the control. Still nothing.

What am I doing wrong here? Should I use some kind of an observable collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you import the System.ComponentModel namespace, then you can use a binding list of string, which will automatically raise events on changes:

```
private void FillItems()
{
    allItems = GetAllItems();
    availableItems = new BindingList<string>(allItems);
    selectedItems = new BindingList<string>();

    itemsListBox.DataSource = availableItems;
    selectedItemsListBox.DataSource = selectedItems;
}

private void addItemButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    object itemsToAdd = itemsListBox.SelectedItems;
    foreach (string item in itemsToAdd) {
        availableItems.Remove(item);
        selectedItems.Add(item);
    }
}
```

This link has further information on the difference between observable collections and binding lists. [difference between ObservableCollection and BindingList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284663/difference-between-observablecollection-and-bindinglist)

Comment: Worked. For posterity: I had to rewrite `SelectedItems` to a separate list because the collection changes, causing the `foreach` to crash.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using ObservableCollections because you do not need to refresh binding yoursef, take a look

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [BindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

DIfference between BindingList and ObservableCollection explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284663/difference-between-observablecollection-and-bindinglist))