# Raise event when a list has new item?

Tags: c#, list, events

I write a control that displays a list of items (in this case just strings). I gave the developer a list of items where he can add and remove items (see code below). I wished there would be a way to be notified when a new item has been added and stuff. So as a reaction the control can update.

```
private List<string> items = new List<string>();

public List<string> Items
{ get { return items; } }
```

How can I do that ? `List<...>` has no events. What can I do ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at [`BindingList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4284805/621962) explains the difference between the two.

Apart from binding, you can subscribe to the change events like so:

`BindingList<T>.ListChanged`:

```
items.ListChanged += (sender, e) => {
    // handle the change notification
};
```

`ObservableCollection<T>.CollectionChanged`:

```
items.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) => {
    // handle the change notification
};
```

Comment: Thx, for additional information and code. Good answer.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`ObservableCollection<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) instead of a `List`. That class comes with built-in support for change notification events.