# Using BindingList in Portable Library

Tags: .net, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged, portable-class-library, bindinglist

So I figured out that binding a list control directly to a `List<T>` doesn't work all that well (property change notification doesn't seem to work) and that `BindingList<T>` should instead be used. The problem is that `BindingList<T>` class is not available in Portable Library projects. I can see `System.ComponentModel` in the list of namespaces, but `BindingList` is not there in it, which means Portable Library projects reference a different `System` assembly than *normal* projects. What's my way out? Do I need to roll out `BindingList<T>` class of my own?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the automatic `PropertyChanged` notification only on adding or deleting items from the list (not on sorting, searching, etc.), you might be satisfied with using `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `BindingList<T>`, which is definitely available in Portable Class Libraries.

For a detailed comparison of the two, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284663/difference-between-observablecollection-and-bindinglist)!

Comment: `ObservableCollection` doesn't work either. I digged it further and the gist of the problem is that `DataGridView` (the control that I'm binding my collection to) does not listen to `PropertyChanged` notifications. A `BindingList` listens to these notifications and thereupon raises `ListChanged` event, which DataGridView listens to and updates itself accordingly. I went ahead and tried implementing `IBindingList` on my collection, but it looks like even that is not available in PCLs. :(