# How to make a listbox automatically update when the source (list) is changed

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listbox, datasource

So I have a listbox with a List as a datasource. What I want is that when I add and remove items from the List, the listbox updates itself.

Right now im able to do it but in a really ugly way. What I do is remove and add the datasource in all the places that I modify the list:

For example:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    formaciones.Add(New ForDias(Formacion, NumericUpDown1.Value))
    ListBox2.DataSource = Nothing
    ListBox2.DataSource = formaciones
End Sub
```

This works, but is there any way of telling the Listbox to check again the datasource without resetting it?

**Edit:**
How I filter:

On the textBox text changed event:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    ListBox2.DataSource = New BindingList(Of Object)((formaciones.Where(Function(i As ForDias) i.Formacion.ToString().Contains(TextBox1.Text))).ToList())
End Sub
```

Comment: Use a `BindingList` or `ObservableCollection` instead of a plain List. The differences of both methods are well explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4284805/2882256).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind a "BindingList(of ForDias)"

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Dim formaciones As New System.ComponentModel.BindingList(Of ForDias)
formaciones.Add(New ForDias(Formacion, NumericUpDown1.Value))
ListBox2.DataSource = Nothing
ListBox2.DataSource = formaciones
End Sub
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, ty. Now im strugling to filter it. The `where` returns me a IEnumerable, that i can convert to a new binding list. I can then bind the ListBox to it. Is there any way of doing it without creating a new binding list each time?

Comment: @Aimnox can you paste the code of your filter please?

Comment: @AlexB. Added the filter

Comment: @Aimnox The filter was correct except the BindingList should be casted to ForDias: `ListBox2.DataSource = New BindingList(Of ForDias) ...`. This seems to be the convenient way of filtering BindingLists, according to some linkes like [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cb7e21ec-4ac9-45ec-824a-e527d194c97c/filtering-a-binding-list?forum=csharpgeneral).

Comment: @Alex The problem is that for compatibility with other parts I need formaciones to be of object. So the binding list needs to be the same