# Why isnt my listbox getting updated with new items when i add them?

Tags: c#, wpf, string, listbox

I'm trying to add a new item to the listbox everytime I press the add button but for some reason it only adds the first one, and if I press it again, it doesnt add the second one.

How I am seeing the code right now is that I create a new list named _items and then I add what ever is in my textbox everytime I press the button then I update the ItemSource aswell.

How do I make it add a new item everytime I press the AddBtn?

```
List<string> _items = new List<string>();


private void addBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _items.Add(recipentTextbox.Text);
    recipientLb.ItemsSource = _items;
}
```

Comment: Am I correct in guessing that this is WPF and you tagged it `winforms` just for the sake of misdirection?

Comment: Deleted the confusing tag.

Answer (score 2):

Try using an `ObservableCollection<string>` instead of `List<string>`. The `ObservableCollection` supports data binding, and will update the target property.

Comment: I used ```BindingList``` what's the difference?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284663/difference-between-observablecollection-and-bindinglist]

Comment: Yeah you need the ObservableCollection. Make sure you initialize it in the constructor and then only clear it never replace it as then the binding will break.

Answer (score 0):

```
ObservableCollection<string> _items = new ObservableCollection<string>();

//  Or whatever your constructor is
public MainWindow()
{
    recipientLb.ItemsSource = _items;
}

private void addBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _items.Add(recipentTextbox.Text);
}
```

Comment: What's the difference betweek ```BindingList``` and ```ObservableCollection``` ?

Comment: @JonnyKhanas ObservableCollection supersedes BindingList. IIRC BindingList is a winforms thing or something; don't use it with WPF

Comment: @JonnyKhanas WPF controls expect collections to implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`, which `ObservableCollection` does and `BindingList` does not.