# Throw CollectionChanged of ObservableCollection when nested Property changes

Tags: c#, mvvm, nested, observablecollection

how to notify a `ObservableCollection<Book>` when a Nested Element changes and i need to know it ?

Perhaps a "`ObservableCollection<Book>`" and "`Book`" has a Member "`Chapter`". And "Chapter" has a String Property called "`Name`" and i change the name value.
How to throw CollectionChanged of ObservableCollection  when Property "Name" in `Name->Chapter -> Book -> ObservableCollection<Book>` changed ??

Is the common way in MVVM to tunnel it through manuell so that CollectionChanged is fired when PropertyChange is fired ??

Thanks :)

---

UPDATE: I found a solution in this post: [ObservableCollection not noticing when Item in it changes (even with INotifyPropertyChanged)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427471/observablecollection-not-noticing-when-item-in-it-changes-even-with-inotifyprop)

-> Use Binding List or kind of a TrulyObservableCollection from the post
   bescause ObservableCollection doesn't relay on item notifications like i 
   already mentioned!
   [difference between ObservableCollection and BindingList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284663/difference-between-observablecollection-and-bindinglist)

-> If u use BindingList remember the disadvantage of this post
http://www.themissingdocs.net/wordpress/?p=465

---

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue in the past. It was caused by my use of Nested Properties and my lack of Notification Propagation.

I solved it by subscribing to the PropertyChanged event each time my object changed. This way I could update my collection when a Nested Property updated.

Make sure that each simple type (e.g. your `Name` property) implements OnPropertyChanged, and then each complex type (e.g. your `Book` and `Chapter` properties) implements the Notification Propagation.

Your Observable Collection should update accordingly.

**Example:**

```
private Book _book;

public Book Book
    {
        get
        {
            return _book;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == _book|| value == null)
                return;

            if (_book!= null)
                _book.PropertyChanged -= BookPropertyChanged;

            _book= value;
            _book.PropertyChanged += BookPropertyChanged;

            UpdateProperties();
        }
    }
```

**Update Methods:**

```
private void BookPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(string.Empty);
    }

public void UpdateProperties()
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(string.Empty);
    }

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. My Problem is not that the property changed is not thrown. My Problem is that I want to fire the collectionchanged event of the collection when the propertychanged of a nested object in the collection is thrown.


Or maybe I just do not understand something in principle :D

Comment: I understand, but your `ObservableCollection` will update if one of its members' properties update. For example, if your `Book` item had a Name property of type `string` and you changed it, then your `ObservableCollection` would update. The issue you are facing is because changing a property of a complex type within your `Book` item will not call `OnPropertyChanged` for your `Book` item. This solution solves that issue and therefore the problem you are facing.

Comment: In my experience, where I had an `ObservableCollection` of type `Item1`, which contained a property of `Item2`, which contained a property of `Item3`, which then contained simple types that I would be modifying. This solution worked for me. I was able to modify any property in my hierarchy and the `ObservableCollection` would update.

Comment: You need Property Changed events of nested properties to notify your Collection so that it will update. This will allow you to tunnel the notifications.

Comment: My User Interface updates if i change the name property in the Collection. I think because WPF uses reflection to look for the INotifyPropertyChanged. But the Collection itself does not get notice of the INotifyPropertyChanged. But i will check it again :/