# VS: Make BindingList sortable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sorting, gridview, datasource

I'm making a project with C# and Visual Studio. The thing is that I'm using a GridView that I want to make sortable (in this case the Prototype Code column), I've created a button which does this:

```
 void SortButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.Sort(PrototypeCodeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending);
        }
```

But in the moment to press the button I'm getting this:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'A DataGridView control can not be
>   ordered if it is bound to an IBindingList that does not support the
>   sort order.'

I've got the **Prototypes.Datasource**, I'm supposing that's what I have to change to make it sortable, but how? 
I'll appreciate your help, thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you can see, the base `BindingList` class [does not support](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/compmod/system/componentmodel/BindingList.cs.html#bfae1257c0f07cce) sorting. You must implement it by yourself.

1. The trivial solution is to derive a new class, which supports sorting. See a simple example [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31418/Implementing-a-Sortable-BindingList-Very-Very-Quic).
2. But for myself I prefer the [CSLA's solution](https://github.com/nschonni/csla-svn/blob/master/Source/Csla/SortedBindingList.cs), which is a completely new reimplementation of the needed interfaces because it provides a sorted view instead of modifying the original underlying collection.

Usage:

```
var myBindingSource = new SortedBindingList<MyType>(myCollection);
myBindingSource.ApplySort(propertyName, ListSortDirection.Ascending);
dataGridView1.DataSource = myBindingSource;
```

Please also note that you don't really need to create a `SortButton` because if the provided data source supports sorting, then the `DataGridView` header will be clickable and it automatically shows the sort direction - see the images in first link.

---

**Update 2020:**

Last year I made my libraries open source so you can use also my [`SortableBindingList<T>`](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.CoreLibraries/blob/master/KGySoft.CoreLibraries/ComponentModel/_Collections/SortableBindingList.cs), which fixes the [performance problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53340758/5114784) of the original `BindingList` as well. You can download it from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/KGySoft.CoreLibraries/).

Comment: At the end, I've used a function which was filtering the data. Now I'm calling it at the beginning without value to search but with a "group by", so it's always filtered, thank you anyway!

Comment: Thank you for making your libraries open source!