# C# ICommand Can Execute

Tags: c#, wpf, interface, icommand

I was trying to understand the ICommand interface.  I built an application with a button that uses a class called RelayCommand which inherits from ICommand. The class looks like this:

```
    class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> _action;
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if(parameter != null)
        {
            _action(parameter);
        }
        else
        {
            _action("Hello World");
        }
    }

    //We need to include CanExecuteChange when using the Interface ICommand 
    //In this case it doesn't actually do anything.
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

}
```

Everytime I trace the the function, I hit the CanExecute method, but nowwhere in my code am I calling this method.  I create a RelayCommand instance like so:

```
Btn_AcceptedAnswer = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(AcceptedAnswer_OnClick));
```

So my question is, when RelayCommand is initiated, how does it know to run CanExecute() and Execute(), and when does it run these?  I know how to implement an event, I am just trying to understand how it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the UI (WPF) that is calling `CanExecute` to know whether the button associated to the command must be enabled or not.

`Execute` is called when the button is pressed.

You can raise (invoke) the `CanExecuteChanged` event when the conditions for `CanExecute` change, to inform the UI to requery it. E.g., the command could be a "Clear" command  related to a list collection bound to a grid-view, combo-box or the like. If the list changes from empty to non-empty or vice-versa, then raise `CanExecuteChanged`. Of course, the button would only be enabled when the list is not empty.

```
public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
{
    return myList.Count > 0;
}

private void OnCanExecuteChanged()
{
    CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}

public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    if(myList.Count > 0) {
        myList.Clear();
        OnCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}
```

When adding elements to the list, you should trigger the event as well. However, this is trickier, as this most likely happens in another command. You will need a way to communicate between the two. A good one would be to use an  [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx) or a [`BindingList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx). Both raise events when the list changes (see: [Difference between ObservableCollection and BindingList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284663/difference-between-observablecollection-and-bindinglist)). The commands could then subscribe the binding list events. An additional effect of `BindingList<T>` is that UI-element it is bound to, automatically updates at list changes.