# Bind List to DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms, datasource

I want to be able to bind a list to a listbox datasource and when the list is modified, the listbox's UI automatically updated. (Winforms not ASP).
Here is a sample :

```
private List<Foo> fooList = new List<Foo>();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Add first Foo in fooList
        Foo foo1 = new Foo("bar1");
        fooList.Add(foo1);

        //Bind fooList to the listBox
        listBox1.DataSource = fooList;
        //I can see bar1 in the listbox as expected
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Add anthoter Foo in fooList
        Foo foo2 = new Foo("bar2");
        fooList.Add(foo2);
        //I expect the listBox UI to be updated thanks to INotifyPropertyChanged, but it's not
    }

class Foo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string bar_ ;
    public string Bar
    {
        get { return bar_; }
        set 
        { 
            bar_ = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Bar");
        }
    }

    public Foo(string bar)
    {
        this.Bar = bar;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return bar_;
    }
}
```

If I replace `List<Foo> fooList = new List<Foo>();` by `BindingList<Foo> fooList = new BindingList<Foo>();` then it works. But I don't want to change the original type of foolist. I would like something like this to work : `listBox1.DataSource = new BindingList<Foo>(fooList);`

EDIT : Also I just read here [List<T> vs BindingList<T> Advantages/DisAdvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243950/listt-vs-bindinglistt-advantages-disadvantages) from Ilia Jerebtsov : "When you set a BindingSource's DataSource to a List<>, it internally creates a BindingList to wrap your list". I think my sample just demonstrates that this is not true : my List<> doesn't seem to be internally wrapped into a BindingList<>.

Comment: List<> doesn't raise any events for observers to know when to update. It doesn't matter whether the observer is a UI component or another list acting as a wrapper. Why the objection to changing to a BindingList when binding is what you need to do?

Comment: I don't want to change the List to BindingList because it's already used as a List everywhere in the project. I will have to replace every methods signatures, I want to avoid to modify what is already stable.

Comment: What if you changed the return type to IList<Foo>? Do you still have the same amount of breaking changes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have a [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx) in you example.

you need to modify it like this to use a BindingSource

```
   var bs = new BindingSource();
   Foo foo1 = new Foo("bar1");
   fooList.Add(foo1);

     bs.DataSource = fooList; //<-- point of interrest

    //Bind fooList to the listBox
    listBox1.DataSource = bs; //<-- notes it takes the entire bindingSource
```

**Edit**

Be aware that (as was pointed out in comments) - the bindingsource does not work with `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: This works. Unfortunately, the ListBox content is not updated when the Bar property of a fooList member is updated elsewhere. There is someone who is annoyed by the same issue here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/f54c125f-6f53-4446-9088-a193f6474059

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
listBox1.DataSource = new BindingList<Foo>(fooList);
```

then

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Foo foo2 = new Foo("bar2");
    (listBox1.DataSource as BindingList<Foo>).Add(foo2);
}
```

This will update fooList without having to change its original type. Also, it will update the ListBox when you change the Bar member like `fooList[1].Bar = "Hello";`

However, you will have to set the `DisplayMember` property of the ListBox to "Bar", **or** to keep the .ToString() override as is in the Foo class definition.

In order to avoid to have to cast every time, I suggest you to use a BindingList variable at the same level as your List definition :

```
private List<Foo> fooList;
private BindingList<Foo> fooListUI;

fooListUI = new BindingList<Foo>(fooList);
listBox1.DataSource = fooListUI;
```

and in the button :

```
Foo foo2 = new Foo("bar2");
fooListUI.Add(foo2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but I found Jens Kloster's solution a little more elegant :)