# How to save the input of datagridview?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

Take a look at my Picture. I wrote dddd ddd in few columns. I want to save this row automatically by clicking on "add" button

or in another words:

After clicking on ADD button i expect the program to save the input but it doesnt work.

Im using Visual Studio - Windows Froms c#. Whats wrong with my code? Any ideas? What am i missing? Thanks for help.

[image]

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        dataGridView1.Visible = true;
        btn_Add.Visible = true;
        button1.Visible = false;
        label1.Visible = true;
        label2.Visible = true;

        textBox2.Visible = true;


        booklist = new List<Book>();
        booklist.Add(new Book("001", "Lord Of the Rings", "J. R. R. Tolkien", "5", "0 Books Avaible"));
        booklist.Add(new Book("002", "The Hobbit", "J. R. R. Tolkien", "5", "2 Books Avaible"));
        booklist.Add(new Book("003", "The Lion, the Witch and the Wardrobe", "C. S. Lewis", "5", "1 Books Avaible"));
        booklist.Add(new Book("004", "The Alchemist", "Paulo Coelho", "5", "3 Books Avaible"));
        booklist.Add(new Book("005", "Think and Grow Rich", "Napoleon Hill", "5", "4 Books Avaible"));
        booklist.Add(new Book("006", "The Da Vinci Code", "Dan Brown", "5", "3 Books Avaible"));
        booklist.Add(new Book("007", "And Then There Were None", "Agatha Christie", "5", "5 Books Avaible"));
        booklist.Add(new Book("008", "She: A History of Adventure", "H. Rider Haggard", "5", "0 Books Avaible"));
        booklist.Add(new Book("009", "Dream of the Red Chamber", "Cao Xueqin", "5", "5 Books Avaible"));
        booklist.Add(new Book("010", "The Catcher in the Rye", "J. D. Salinger", "5", "5 Books Avaible"));
        booklist.Add(new Book("011", "The Little Prince", "Antoine de Saint-Exupéry", "5", "5 Books Avaible"));
        booklist.Add(new Book("012", "Lolita", "Vladimir Nabokov", "5", "3 Books Avaible"));
        booklist.Add(new Book("013", "The Name of the Rose", "Umberto Eco", "5", "1 Books Abaible"));
        booklist.Add(new Book("014", "Black Beauty", "Anna Sewell", "5", "2 Books Avaible"));
        booklist.Add(new Book("015", "Charlotte's Web", "E.B. White", "5", "0 Books Avaible"));
        booklist.Add(new Book("016", "Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire", "J. K. Rowling", "5", "2 Books Avaible"));
        booklist.Add(new Book("017", "Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban", "J. K. Rowling", "5", "1 Books Avaible"));
        booklist.Add(new Book("018", "Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets", "J. K. Rowling", "5", "4 Books Avaible"));
        booklist.Add(new Book("019", "Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince", "J. K. Rowling", "5", "3 Books Avaible"));
        booklist.Add(new Book("020", "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone", "J. K. Rowling", "5", "3 Books Avaible"));
        booklist.Add(new Book("021", "Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix", "J. K. Rowling", "5", "4 Books Avaible"));
        booklist.Add(new Book("022", "Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows", "J. K. Rowling", "5", "3 Books Avaible"));
        booklist.Add(new Book("023", "", "", "", ""));
        booklist.Add(new Book("024", "", "", "", ""));
        booklist.Add(new Book("025", "", "", "", ""));
        booklist.Add(new Book("026", "", "", "", ""));
        dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();

        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = booklist;


    }

    private void btn_Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btn_Add.Visible = false;
        button3.Visible = true;
        dataGridView1.Visible = true;
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = true;


    }



    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var textbox = (TextBox)sender;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.Text))
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = booklist;
            return;
        }

        var search = booklist.Where(b => b.Name.Contains(textbox.Text)).ToList();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = search;

        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString()); 
    }
```

Comment: Where you expect to save?

Comment: As @SeM said, you store your books in a `list` that is not now preserved between program runs. Your `btn_Add_Click` does not add anything to that `booklist` - and how do you expect it would save anything then?

Comment: As it [explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2244039/1566267), using `List<>` internally creates `BindingList<>`, so there's the binding.  Try to update data with
`datagridview1.EndEdit();
datagridview1.Refresh();` Than check the contents of `booklist`. You could add buttons to save to /load from disk, or, that is preferable, use database.

Comment: i tried it but it doesnt help

Comment: __You__ need to answer the basic question: WHERE do you want the data be saved??? - A simple option is to save to a txt file, tab-sparated. First chnage your code to read in from such a file instead of hard-coding the data! Then learn how to save data: Either rewrite the whole file (simple as it includes both new and changes records) or restrict to saving new records by appending to the file. Later you should consider using a database and also using xml!

Comment: in here 
            booklist = new List<Book>();

Comment: Well add the check `dataGridView1.Rows[i].IsNewRow` to LP's answer then

Comment: right before the `bookList.Add(new Book()` then only newly added rows will get added to that list.. Of course, it still will not be saved for the next program run.. xml can do that rather easily.

Comment: Also: Are you really __hiding__ buttons? Not a good practice imo unless another one shows up in their place. Instead __disable__ when the funczion is not __applicable__ so the users won't __worry__ about disappearing ui elements!

Answer (score 1):

As it is shown in documentation example, [you have to create `BindingSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fbk67b6z(v=vs.110).aspx). `List` cannot serve as `BindingSource` ([see that SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141953/bind-list-to-datasource))

```
private BindingSource bindingSource1;
....
bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
bindingSource1.DataSource = booklist;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
```

Clicking the ***Add button*** should finish editing mode if the current string is edited:

```
datagridview1.EndEdit();
datagridview1.Refresh();
```

[The other solution from SO question is `BindingList`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141953/bind-list-to-datasource)

```
private List<Book> booklist; // your book list as usual
private BindingList<Book> booklistUI; // add this list
...
//at the end of button1_Click
booklistUI = new BindingList<Book>(booklist);
dataGridView1.DataSource = booklistUI;
```

Answer (score 1):

A manually way, I hope you get the idea.

**Method:**

```
    public void Add()
    {         
        List<Book> bookList = new List<Book>();

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            bookList.Add(new Book()
            {
                Id = (string)dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["Id"].Value,
                Name = (string)dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["Name"].Value,
                Author = (string)dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["Author"].Value,
                NumberOfBooks = (string)dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["NumberOfBooks "].Value,
                Available = (string)dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["Available"].Value
            });
        }

       //You can do anything now
    }
```

**Add click event:**

```
private void btn_Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btn_Add.Visible = false;
    button3.Visible = true;
    dataGridView1.Visible = true;
    dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
    Add();
}
```