# How to tell Gridviews to refresh the databound item of a row?

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radgridview

I'm using a RadGridView to display items. On a doubleclick the user comes to a detail view where he can edit the contents and then comes back (both usercontrols are displayed as tabs on screen and are thus existing simultaneously).

I'm using a working method to update the edited list in the grid view without reloading the whole gridview:

```
 dataRow = (GridViewRowInfo)element.Data;
 Worker displayedWorker = (Worker)edataRow.DataBoundItem;
 Worker changedWorkerFromDataBase = GetWorkerFromDataBase(displayedWorker.WorkerNumber).FirstOrDefault();

 List<Worker> tableDataSource = (List<Worker>)MyGridView.DataSource;

 int indexInTableDataSource = tableDataSource.IndexOf(tableDataSource.Where(e => e.WorkerNumber == displayedWorker.WorkerNumber).First());

 tableDataSource[indexInTableDataSource] = changedWorkerFromDataBase;
 dataRow.InvalidateRow();
```

Like mentioned this code works, but when I change the IndexOf method to:

```
 int indexInTableDataSource = tableDataSource.IndexOf(displayedWorker);
```

it doesn't work any longer as expected. The above code works once and only once after a second save the objects stored inside the MyGridView.DataSource and the one stored inside the dataRow.DataBoundItem are seen as being different resulting in the indexOf returning -1.

This behaviour surprised me quite a lot especially as the first method works without problems and I had thought that the dataBound item of the row is just a pointer towards the items inside the GridView datasource.

Thus my question here is: Can (after the update is done) I tell the row to update/refresh its databound item so that it is equal again to the one from the gridview (aka seen as the same object) ?

Comment: Where it the above code used, in some event handler? Also, what is "element"?

Answer (score 1):

First off: If you have sorting/grouping enabled, the index in the datasource might not correspond with the index in the radgridview (see [Childrows vs Rows](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-rows-rows-vs-childrows.html)).

I have worked on a similar scenario with a radgridview and a detailview.

- To notify the radgridview that a propertyvalue is changed your `Worker` class needs to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. [About INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- Change your datasource type from List to BindingList as this list has events raised when the list is changed. [About BindingList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Now you should be able to alter the instance of your `Worker` class and the changes should be picked up immediatly in your radgridview.

Comment: For the index part: Yepp was also a thought of mine initially but when I tested it mutliple times I made sure that the sorting, filterin,.... so all things taht I can do are just the same for both save attempts so theoretically the index in the datasource should be the same at both times (if I use the working method the index even IS the same according to that)

Comment: I believe the IndexOf-method will check for reference-equality.. try overriding the Equals method in your Worker-class.

Comment: Yes the indexof checks for reference equality which causes the problem (although I'm still not sure WHY the reference isn't equal any longer after the first save)

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your case is coming from the fact that for the grid's DataSource you are using List, which does not support notifications. If you switch to BindingList you will be good to go. Here is a sample:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        AddGrid();

        BindingList<Worker> lst = new BindingList<Worker>() { new Worker() { ID = 1, Name = "Adam" }, new Worker() { ID = 2, Name = "Eva" } };
        radGridView1.DataSource = lst;
    }

    class Worker
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    private void radButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Worker displayedWorker = (Worker)radGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
        BindingList<Worker> tableDataSource = (BindingList<Worker>)radGridView1.DataSource;
        int indexInTableDataSource = tableDataSource.IndexOf(displayedWorker);

        Worker changedWorkerFromDataBase = new Worker() { ID = 1, Name = "new name" };
        tableDataSource[indexInTableDataSource] = changedWorkerFromDataBase;
    }
```

More on the difference between List and BindingList can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2244039/298871