# How to add new row when user press enters on last column of DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

- How do I jump to the next row when user presses enter on the last column of `DataGridView`?
- This code also gives me an error which I need to resolve:

  > Index is out of range must be non-negative and less than the size of
  >   collection.

  ```
  private void DataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
  {
      try
      {
          if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
          {
              e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
              int iColumn = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
              int iRow = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
              if (iColumn >= DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 2)
                  DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1[0, iRow + 1];
              else
                  DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1[iColumn + 1, iRow];
          }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString())
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: What line is the error being thrown on? How far are you with adding the next row?

Comment: There won't be a next row since it's the last row. If the last row is selected, you can go start from the beginning. If you really want a next row, you'll have too add a row first.

Comment: @krillgar error is thrown when the last column is hit.

Comment: @TheLazySloth I will add a new row, but how do I detect if a last column is reached.

Comment: I don't have C# on any of my laptops atm so I can't do my own tests so forgive me if I'm wrong. You could get the last column with DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1. We subtract one since our column index starts at 0.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle this using `DataGridView.KeyDown`, but you would miss the case where the user hits <kbd>Enter</kbd> while editing a cell. To catch all cases, derive your own class from `DataGridView` and override `ProcessCmdKey`. Using the logic suggested in comments above, when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is detected for the last Row, add another row. Don't worry about manually changing the `CurrentCell`. Let the base class handle that work itself.

```
public class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        bool enterKeyDetected = keyData == Keys.Enter;
        bool isLastRow = this.CurrentCell.RowIndex == this.RowCount - 1;

        if (enterKeyDetected && isLastRow)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter detected on {0},{1}", this.CurrentCell.RowIndex, this.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex);

            // Add the new row.
        }

        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

You need only pay attention to *how* you add the new row depending on your `DataSource`:

- None

  ```
  this.Rows.Add();
  ```
- A `DataTable`

  ```
  DataTable dt = (DataTable)this.DataSource;
  dt.Rows.Add();
  ```
- A `BindingList<T>` (see [List vs BindingList](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2244039/3773066))

  ```
  BindingList<T> bl= (BindingList<T>)this.DataSource;
  bl.Add(new T());
  ```
- Etc.

Lastly, just replace your instance of `DataGridView` with an instance of this custom one.

---

All that said, if you don't have a `DataSource`, just setting `DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = true` should suffice since editing the `NewRow` will trigger another to be added.