# How to auto add new line in data grid view of vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, datagridview

We have manually created grid columns and at the "cellenter" event we are filling all column values.

At the last column when we press enter, require to add one new line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataGridView: How can I make the enter key add a new line instead of changing the current cell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030542/datagridview-how-can-i-make-the-enter-key-add-a-new-line-instead-of-changing-th)

Comment: Also see a solution I've written [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41020829/3773066).