# Data Grid View won't refresh after updating

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, datagrid

I am doing simple database client in c#. Right now I'm using entity framework, everything seems to be fine, but after adding a new record to database it won't update. Here's my code :

```
        private void AddClientConfirmButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainForm frm = new MainForm();
        var newClient = new Klienci
        {
            Imie = FirstNameTextBox.Text,
            Nazwisko = LastNameTextBox.Text,
            Adres = AdressTextBox.Text,
            Telefon = TelephoneTextBox.Text,
            Email = EmailTextBox.Text,
            Status = StatusComboBox.Text
        };
        frm.UpdateDb(newClient);
        Close();
    }
```

Here's UpdateDb method:

```
        public void UpdateDb(Klienci newClient)
    {
        var dataContext = new BAKKEntities();
        dataContext.Klienci.Add(newClient);
        dataContext.SaveChanges();
        dataContext.Dispose();
        LoadData();
    }
```

And there's LoadData:

```
        public void LoadData()
    {
        var dataContext = new BAKKEntities();
        var clientList = from r in dataContext.Klienci
                         select new
                         {
                             Imie = r.Imie,
                             Nazwisko = r.Nazwisko,
                             Adres = r.Adres,
                             Telefon = r.Telefon,
                             Email = r.Email,
                             Status = r.Status,
                         };
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = clientList.ToList();
        ClientsDataGridView.DataSource = bs;
        dataContext.Dispose();
    }
```

I have to run my program again if I want to refresh data, and that's not so comfortable

Comment: I don't know  if the method exists for that class, but try `.ToBindingList()` rather than `.ToList()`

Comment: It doesn't exist

Comment: Have you considered using WPF instead of winforms? WPF's data bindings are simply amazing after you get used to them.

Answer (score 0):

Just set to null and then assign the value,

```
 BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
 bs.DataSource = clientList.ToList();
 ClientsDataGridView.DataSource = null;
 ClientsDataGridView.DataSource = bs;
 dataContext.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bs.ResetBindings(false);
ClientsDataGridView.DataSource = typeof(List); 
ClientsDataGridView.DataSource = bs;
```

Answer (score 0):

To use ToBindingList() like Noceo said, you have to import System.Data.Entity.
do something like :

```
DataContext.Klienci.Load()
```

For loading all the clients, and  :

```
bs.Datasource = DataContext.Klienci.Local.ToBindingList()
```

To link to your data binding. After that, it will updated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning a `List<T>` to your `BindingSource.DataSource`, assign a [BindingList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to it.

You don't have to create a new `BindingSource` every time you want to update the collection of `Klienci` for you `DataGridView`. Do this only once during initialization and assign the `BindingList<T>` to the `BindingSource.DataSource`

The following is only done during initialization (InitializeComponent()?)

```
DataGridView myDataGridView = new DataGridView();
BindingSouce myBindingSource = new BindingSource();
myDataGridView.DataSource = myBindingSource();
```

Whenever you need to re-fill your DataGridView with all your Klienci:

```
using (var dataContext = new BAKKEntities())
{
    IEnumerable<Klienci> clients = dataContext.Klienci
        .Select(client => new Klienci()
        {
            Imie = client.Imie,
            Nazwisko = client.Nazwisko,
            Adres = client.Adres,
            Telefon = client.Telefon,
            Email = client.Email,
            Status = client.Status,
         });
     myBindingsource.DataSource = new BindingList<Klienci>(clients.ToList())
}
```

Sorry I use linq method-syntax, I'm more familiar with that. The main importance is that you convert your retrieved sequence of Klienci into a BindingList and then assign that to the BindingSource that is already connected to the DataGridView.DataSource.

You might find the following useful [Stackoverflow: List vs BindingList Advantages/DisAdvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243950/listt-vs-bindinglistt-advantages-disadvantages)

Did you notice I used a `using` statement. This is to make sure your DataContext is disposed, even if you have an exception.

By the way: if you want your datagridview to be sortable, consider using a [SortableBindingList](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31418/Implementing-a-Sortable-BindingList-Very-Very-Quic). Usage is the same as a BindingList, except that you