# In wpf Clear ListBox items at Runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, textblock

I am using wpf `listbox,` i cannot able to clear the list when am calling the reload data function, i just want to reload new data at runtime,while page loading it loads the data correctly, when i refresh the new data is fetched in itemsource i can see that in debug mode, but no new data in listbox, old data remains in the list, i cant even clear, when i call list.items.clear(),  i tried lot ways, is there any problem in my XAML binding, the following is my code.

XAML:

```
 <ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding}"   HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" x:Name="lstbxindex"  Foreground="White" FontSize="20px" Height="400" BorderBrush="#555555" Margin="10,34,16,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="322" Background="#555555" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>    
                <DataTemplate>

                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5" >

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtblckroundhour" Height="40px" Width="55px" Text="{Binding RoundedHours}"  FontSize="14" Background="#555555" Loaded="txtblckroundhour_Loaded"  Foreground="White"></TextBlock>

                            <Label x:Name="items" MouseDoubleClick="items_MouseDoubleClick" Content="{Binding ProjectRow.Name}" Background="#555555" FontSize="20" Loaded="items_Loaded" Visibility="Visible"  Margin="35,0,0,0"  Width="230" Foreground="White"></Label>
                        </StackPanel>


                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <ComboBox  Height="40px" Width="290" Margin="-230,0,0,0" Loaded="ComboBox_Loaded" Visibility="Hidden"  IsEditable="True"  FontSize="20"  Background="White"  Foreground="Black"></ComboBox>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <!--<ComboBox  x:Name="ComboBox_AddItem"  Height="40px" Width="290" Margin="-35,35,0,0"  Loaded="ComboBox_AddItem_Loaded"  IsEditable="True"  FontSize="20"  Background="White" Visibility="Hidden" Foreground="Black"></ComboBox>-->
                    </WrapPanel>
                </DataTemplate>



            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Get the list of values

```
private List<ProjectInformation> projectInformationList1 = new List<ProjectInformation>();
```

// Here define the actual binding of the userinterface listbox to the in-memory list of objects.

```
 foreach (DtoProjectsRow row in projectsTable.Rows)
                {

                    projectInformationList1.Add(new ProjectInformation(row));
                }

  lstbxindex.DataContext = projectInformationList1;
```

In SO I tried some solution but unfortunately it is not work for me. Last I tried,

XAML.cs page

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyListProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyList", typeof(ObservableCollection<String>), typeof(Window));

        public ObservableCollection<String> MyList
        {
            get
            {
                return (ObservableCollection<String>)GetValue(MyListProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(MyListProperty, value);
            }
        }
```

XAML:

```
 <ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding **ElementName=Window**}"   HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" x:Name="lstbxindex"  Foreground="White" FontSize="20px" Height="400" BorderBrush="#555555" Margin="10,34,16,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="322" Background="#555555" >
```

Using this above solution listitems are clear but when pageloading the listboxitems are clear but I don't want to clear the iistboxitems, after updating the values from user it will reload the updated value in listbox.

lstbxindex.ItemsSource = null;

But its not work.For pageload listbox loaded all items,every 15 min interval it will call the load function for firsttime it will reload the updatedvalues but second time it will reload the updated values and previous values remains in listbox again.

Comment: What exception is thrown?

Comment: what exceptions you are getting ?

Comment: there is no exception thrown. it simply reload the whole data (with updated value) again In listbox.

Comment: A few things, first don't do `lstbxindex.ItemsSource = null;`. If you have a ViewModel don't use code behind as it can get confusing. You declare `private List<ProjectInformation> projectInformationList1 = new List<ProjectInformation>();` but in your foreach you use `projectInformationList.Add(new ProjectInformation(row));`, is that a typo? Finally, try a TwoWay binding like `ItemsSource="{Binding projectInformationList1, Mode=TwoWay}"`

Comment: @keyurPATEL but it will clear listboxitem when pageload.

Comment: Where is your "reload data function" and how do you clear the list?

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood initially thinking you were using MVVM, instead you're populating the ListView datasource from code behind.

Your line `lstbxindex.DataContext = projectInformationList1;` does not set the Data as you'd think. Instead try `lstbxindex.DataContext = this;` which means you're telling your view to look for the data source in code behind.

As such, I suggest adding `using System.ComponentModel;` and using [BindingList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx), a comparison is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243950/listt-vs-bindinglistt-advantages-disadvantages).

```
private BindingList<ProjectInformation> projectInformationList1 = new BindingList<ProjectInformation>();
```

And you just need this once:

```
foreach (DtoProjectsRow row in projectsTable.Rows)
{
    projectInformationList1.Add(new ProjectInformation(row));
}
lstbxindex.DataSource = projectInformationList1;
```

As mentioned in the comments, if you did not use `ItemsSource="{Binding projectInformationList1}"` as I suggested in a comment to your question, this is the alternative:

```
private ObservableCollection<ProjectInformation> projectInformationList1 = new ObservableCollection<ProjectInformation>();

foreach (DtoProjectsRow row in projectsTable.Rows)
{
    projectInformationList1.Add(new ProjectInformation(row));
}
lstbxindex.DataContext = projectInformationList1;
```

Comment: `lstbxindex.DataContext = this` won't work with `ItemsSource="{Binding}"`.

Comment: And use ObservableCollection instead of BindingList

Comment: @Keyur PATEL Thank you, But now it shows invalidoperation exception is thrown

Comment: On which line is it thrown?

Comment: While scroll the listbox, it will added the updated values and previous values remains same.then it will shows invalidOperationException.

Comment: If its not too much trouble, could you also add to your question the code you use to add/clear the list?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a view model class with a collection property, e.g. like this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ProjectInformation> Projects { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<ProjectInformation>();
}
```

Set the DataContext of your Window or Page in XAML like this:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

and bind the ListBox like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}">
    ...
</ListBox>
```

To clear all items in the source collection, access the DataContext in code behind:

```
var vm = (ViewModel)DataContext;
vm.Projects.Clear();
```

---

Edit: Instead of assigning the DataContext in XAML, you may as well do it in code behind, even before the Page or Window is initialized:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    DataContext = new ViewModel();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: Inside the listbox I have two controls one is textblock and other one is label, inside the textblock I want to bind the items.

Comment: In vm.Projects.Clear() in this line it will throw a null reference exceptions

Comment: Use your debugger to check if `vm` is null or the `Projects` property.

Comment: I checked vm is null

Comment: Then you probably accessed the DataContext property before the Page or Window was loaded. See my edit.

Comment: I accessed the DataContext after the window was loaded. 15 min interval I will access the load function in my application

Comment: Then you did not properly assign the view model object to the DataContext property. See my edit.

Comment: vm=(ViewModel)DataContext; there data count=0;

Comment: can't able to add<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

Answer (score -1):

Added the line in loadfunction, Initially set null for ItemSource and then set null to the list object

```
lstbx.ItemsSource=null;
 lstbx.Items.Clear();
  ProjectInfoList1=null;
```

it will clear the listboxitems and reload with updated values only.

```
private BindingList<ProjectInfo> projectInfoList1 = new BindingList<ProjectInfo>();
        Public void loadfunction()
        {

        lstbx.ItemsSource=null;
        lstbx.Items.Clear();
        ProjectInformationList1=null;
        foreach (DtoProRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            projectInfoList1.Add(new ProjectInfo(row));
        }
        lstbx.DataContext = projectInfoList1;
        }
```

Comment: This makes not much sense, as setting `lstbx.ItemsSource = null` invalidates the ItemsSource Binding that you declared in XAML. Please try to understand how data binding to collections *actually* works in WPF. Read these articles: [Data Binding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview) and [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview). Right now, you're doing it all wrong. You write *Learning!!!* on your profile page, so listen to what experts tell you.