# WPF: Binding listview itemsource from viewmodel in MVVM

Tags: wpf, listview, itemssource

I am trying to set ItemSource property for listview without success.

**View (xaml)**:

```
<ListView Margin="10" Name="MyLv" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
....
</ListView>
```

**Code-Behind Constructor (xaml.cs)**:

```
    public MyView()           
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

**ViewModel**:

```
    private List<DataModel> lstData = null;
    public MyViewModel()
    {          
        this.lstData = this.LoadData();  // this connects to a database an extract info to be loaded in listview
    }
```

Data Model:

```
public class DataModel
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }     
}
```

Before this, I was loading the listview from code-behind and it was working, but now I want to load it from my viewmodel and I do not know how can I make it work.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44646122/1136211

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the code you posted, there are a couple of problems:

1. You haven't set the `DataContext` of the view. You typically want to set this to an instance of your view model class.
2. The `ViewModel` doesn't expose the list as a public property. WPF bindings only work on public properties. The `ItemsSource` should be bound to this property, and not to the `DataContext` itself.

Finally, you probably want the collection in the `ViewModel` to be an [`ObservableCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx). This way, when changes are made to the collection, the list in the UI will be automatically updated.

Comment: Basically, `<ListView Margin="10" Name="MyLv" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=lstData}">`, **but** this won't work until you fix everything else @Andy mentions in this answer first.