# How to output parts of a string onto a new line in a listbox C#

Tags: c#, string, list, split, listbox

I am having trouble figuring out how to split a concatenated string onto new lines. Am pretty new to c#/coding in general, and am looking for a relatively easy method to show this.

I am not trying to just get an answer, have spent a lot of time researching different split methods online, but most I have seen don't show splitting a concatenated string.

This is my current code:

```
private string SearchbyPayRate(string term, List<string> PeopleList)

    {try
        {
            string result = "not found"; //initial value of search result


            //prepare for the search item from parameter

            int employeeid = int.Parse(term);

            for (int i = 0; i < PeopleList.Count; i++) //The list is search through one by one
            {   //In order to separate employee id from other items in a line, each line is split into 3 items (fields) by ","
                string[]vals = PeopleList[i].Split(',');
                int id = int.Parse(vals[0]); //Employment id is at the first item
                if (id == employeeid) //Found
                {
                    decimal hours = decimal.Parse(tbxwageworkinghrs.Text);
                    decimal payrate = decimal.Parse(vals[2]);
                    decimal wage = hours * payrate;

                    result = "Employee " + vals[0] + " Wage Details:" + "Pay rate is $" + vals[2] + " Working hours is " + hours + "Wage is $" + wage;

                }
            }
            return result; //Send a single result string back to the main program which calls this method
        }  
    catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
   }

    private void btngrosspay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {try

        {//Saved data file needs to be loaded before the search
            if (People == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No data is loaded from saved file!", "Click button \"Load File\""); }
                //Display special symbol, \ is used
                else
            {   //A single variable is used to receive only one search result by calling a SearchbyPayRate method
                //This method has two parameters, employee id from textbox and a list of loaded people data from the daved file
                string eidResult = SearchbyPayRate(tbxwageempid.Text, People);
                //Output the single result
                lbxwagedetails.Items.Clear();
                lbxwagedetails.Items.Add(eidResult);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Currently the listbox output is all on one line like this:

Employee 1 Wage Details: Pay rate is $20 Working hours is 25 Wage is $500.00

I want the listbox output to look like this:

Employee 1 Wage Details:
Pay rate is $20 
Working hours is 25 
Wage is $500.00

Any suggestions/ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Why are you using strings instead of a `Person` class?

Comment: Also, why does your method accept a `string` for `term` when it's expected to be an `int`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set Return result string with comma separate, add comma where ever you want break line like **string eidResult = "Result : 10%,Marks :5"**. Now when you add in ListBox with Using **ListBox.AddRange(eidResult.Split(',').ToArray())**, I Hope you'll get your solution

```
      private string SearchbyPayRate(string term, List<string> PeopleList)

     {try
         {
          string result = "not found"; //initial value of search result


        //prepare for the search item from parameter

        int employeeid = int.Parse(term);

        for (int i = 0; i < PeopleList.Count; i++) //The list is search through one by one
        {   //In order to separate employee id from other items in a line, each line is split into 3 items (fields) by ","
            string[]vals = PeopleList[i].Split(',');
            int id = int.Parse(vals[0]); //Employment id is at the first item
            if (id == employeeid) //Found
            {
                decimal hours = decimal.Parse(tbxwageworkinghrs.Text);
                decimal payrate = decimal.Parse(vals[2]);
                decimal wage = hours * payrate;

                result = "Employee " + vals[0] + " Wage Details:" + ",Pay rate is $" + vals[2] + ",Working hours is " + hours + ",Wage is $" + wage;

            }
        }
        return result; //Send a single result string back to the main program which calls this method
    }  
catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
    }

private void btngrosspay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{try

    {//Saved data file needs to be loaded before the search
        if (People == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No data is loaded from saved file!", "Click button \"Load File\""); }
            //Display special symbol, \ is used
            else
        {   //A single variable is used to receive only one search result by calling a SearchbyPayRate method
            //This method has two parameters, employee id from textbox and a list of loaded people data from the daved file
            string eidResult = SearchbyPayRate(tbxwageempid.Text, People);
            //Output the single result
            lbxwagedetails.Items.Clear();
            lbxwagedetails.Items.AddRange(eidResult.Split(',').ToArray());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this different from OP?

Comment: result set with comma separate, and using split for get array.

Comment: Fine, but you should explain this in your answer. As is it seems to be a simple copy/paste.

Comment: Thanks very much, this worked perfectly. I did have another fix using a textbox, with the multi line properties set to true and read only. And then combining with the below return result using \r\n for line breaks:                                               
                                                                                                            
result = "Employee " + vals[0] + " Wage Details:" + "\r\nPay rate is $" + vals[2] + "\r\nWorking hours is " + hours + "\r\nWage is $" + wage;

Answer (score 0):

I suggest parsing into `out` parameters referring to a [`BindingList<String>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243950/listt-vs-bindinglistt-advantages-disadvantages).

You could alternatively use an `ArrayList<String>` (or possibly some other `class` or `struct`?) and return *that* instead of a `string`. After all, the idea of extracting your strings from CSV format was to turn them into *multiple* strings, right? Recombining them is just a step backwards.

You'll then want `btngrosspay_Click` to iterate on the multiple items in the List (whichever one you used; they both iterate the same way), to add each item to the list as a separate list entry... or if you're using a `class` or `struct`, you'll want to individually add each member as an item to the list.