# ComboBox and ListBox is not displaying data i am adding to it

Tags: c#, winforms, datasource

So i have this ComboBox and ListBox i am trying data bindings for the first time as i am adding data to them its not showing in the windows form

```
private List<PersonModel> AvailableTeamMember = new List<PersonModel>();

public CreateTeamForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
     
    ListsWireUp();

    CreateSampleData();
}

private void CreateSampleData()
{
    AvailableTeamMember.Add(new PersonModel { FirstName = "abc", LastName = "def" });
    AvailableTeamMember.Add(new PersonModel { FirstName = "jack", LastName = "smith" });
}

private void ListsWireUp()
{
    SelectTeamMemberDropDown.DataSource = AvailableTeamMember;
    SelectTeamMemberDropDown.DisplayMember = "Name";
}
```

```
public class Personmodel{

public string FirstName {get;set;}
public string LastName {get;set;}
public string Name{
get{ return $"{FirstName} {LastName}";}
}
}
```

I have tried some-of the solutions like putting data-source at last but that doesn't work for me. My Windows form is working but not displaying anything.

Comment: This code is part of *something*, unless you have a Form that has a Property `Name` (not possible) that returns FirstName + LastName. Is it a class? Other? How did you reference this `SelectTeamMemberDropDown` Control in there?

Comment: This code sample in the OP is incomplete and really doesn't do anything (ie: your missing the code that calls the methods). Please post a complete [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which others can use to re-create the issue that you're facing.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Tutorial: Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2022)

Comment: Like others mentioned, where are you calling the 2 CreateSampleData & ListsWireUp methods. Show full/relevant code.

Comment: @jimi yup this was a mistake on my end the thing is the code is two different classes one is person model one is the form calling it and the mistake was i was calling wireup before sample data thats why it was rendering it empty

Comment: The following may be of interest: [List<T> vs BindingList<T> Advantages/DisAdvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243950/listt-vs-bindinglistt-advantages-disadvantages), [ValueMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember?view=windowsdesktop-8.0), and [SelectedValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue?view=windowsdesktop-8.0)

Answer (score 0):

In your code `Name` property is not directly part of the `PersonModel` and the `CreateSampleData()` method is not being called before `ListsWireUp()`, so the `AvailableTeamMember` list remains empty.

So make sure that your `PersonModel` class contains the `Name` property and also, call `CreateSampleData()` before `ListsWireUp()` to populate the `AvailableTeamMember` list.

```
public class PersonModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
        }
    }
}

private List<PersonModel> AvailableTeamMember = new List<PersonModel>();

private void CreateSampleData()
{
    AvailableTeamMember.Add(new PersonModel { FirstName = "abc", LastName = "def" });
    AvailableTeamMember.Add(new PersonModel { FirstName = "jack", LastName = "smith" });
}

private void ListsWireUp()
{
    CreateSampleData(); // Call this to populate the list
    SelectTeamMemberDropDown.DataSource = AvailableTeamMember;
    SelectTeamMemberDropDown.DisplayMember = "Name";
}
```

Comment: the name is the part of person model it was mistake on my end but ya as u said i was calling wire up function before thats why it was empty such a silly mistake